# scss - @media query within a class not working for subselections

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying to target the children of a certain class to have different attributes when the screen width meets a certain width. However, the `@media` query isn't working for the children unless I have `!important` applied. Is this some kind of specificity issue that I'm missing?

HTML:

```
<div class=test>
  <div class="a">
    test block1
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    test block2
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.test {
  display: flex;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    display: block;

    div + div {
      margin: 0;
    }     

  }
  div + div {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  > div {
    width: 50px;
  }
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3641apf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3641apf/1/). you need to change the position of media query

```
.test {
  display: flex;


  div + div {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  > div {
    width: 50px;
  }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    display: block;

    div + div {
      margin: 0;
    }     

  }
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution.

```
    <div class=test>
    <div class="a">
 test block1
  </div>
<div class="b">
test block2
</div>
```

```
.test {
 display: flex;
}  
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .test a,.test b{
        display: none;
    }
}     

}
div + div {
margin-left: 5px;
 }

   div {
width: 50px;
 }
}

.a {
 background-color: red;
 }

   .b {
  background-color: blue
```

}

Comment: please understand the question before answering. This question is specific to `scss`